# Keep reference to the calling object when resolving an angular promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

### The Problem

When resolving promises the javascript context changes to `Window #` - meaning I can't refer back to the object that is resolving the promise, and either use or change any of its variables.

I can refer back to it if I use a `that = this` hack, but the problem with that if I have multiple objects using this hack they'll all share the same `window.that` variable and they'll get mixed up.

Here's some sample code I've created to demonstrate this problem:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
//Represents a service that makes call to the server. 
//Returns angular promises
app.service('MyService', function($q, $timeout){

    this.evenOrOdd = function(i){

        console.log("even or odd for: " + i);
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function(){    
                console.log("starting time out");
                if (parseInt(i)) {

                    if (i%2 === 1) deffered.resolve("Odd:" + i);
                    else deffered.resolve("Even" + i);                  
                }
                else deffered.reject("That's not an int!");
            }, 3000);

        return deffered.promise;

    };


});


//Represents some business object 
//We may want several of these
app.factory('MyFactory', function(MyService){

    return function() {

            //Some object specific variable
            this.rand = Math.random();

            console.log("creating new factory object with rand = " + this.rand);

            this.oddCheck = function(i){            
                var promise = MyService.evenOrOdd(i);

                that = this;        //the problem is here

                promise.then(function(value){               
                    console.log(that.rand + "|" + value);

                    }
                );  

                promise.catch(function(value){
                    console.log(that.rand + "|" + value);
                });

            };


    };

});


//Our controller, makes calls to update multiple objects at the same time
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyFactory) {

    $scope.factoryObject = new MyFactory();
    $scope.factoryObject2 = new MyFactory();

    $scope.myClick = function(){    

        $scope.factoryObject.oddCheck(10);
        $scope.factoryObject2.oddCheck(11);

    };


    }
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "app.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body  ng-app="myApp" >

    <div ng-controller = "MyController">

        <button ng-click = "myClick()">Click me</button>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When we run this we get:

```
creating new factory object with rand = 0.10776704256566871
app.js (line 38)
creating new factory object with rand = 0.5952598424233105
app.js (line 38)
even or odd for: 10
app.js (line 8)
even or odd for: 11
app.js (line 8)
starting time out
app.js (line 12)
0.5952598424233105|Even10   //Rand is wrong
app.js (line 46)
starting time out
app.js (line 12)
0.5952598424233105|Odd:11
app.js (line 46)
```

How else do I keep track of where the object is when resolving promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `var that = this;` otherwise you're using a global variable that is overwritten all the time - or look into bind - e.g.

```
this.oddCheck = function(i){            
    var promise = MyService.evenOrOdd(i);
    promise.then(function(value){               
        console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);
    }.bind(this));  

    promise.catch(function(value){
        console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);
    }.bind(this));

};
```

and finally - the above function can also be written like:

```
this.oddCheck = function(i){            
    MyService.evenOrOdd(i)
    .then(function(value){               
        console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function(value){
        console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer use this way. You should return object. You can refer on itself inside that object. This is example: http://jsbin.com/memaha/12/edit?js,console

Also you can use Ecmascript 6 arrow function. It's provide parent context.`.then(res => console.log(this.rand)//this will be outter function)`